# In ember, how to get notified each time new partial loaded after the route change

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to manipulate the `DOM` which is generated/attached after the route changes in `ember`. so I need to  call a hook method after the page render successfully (for all partial), it is not specific to components. Just want to get notified each time the new partial loaded successfully after the route change?

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know for component there is `didInsertElement` hook but there is no hook in route will be called after page rendered successfully. but there is hacky workaround you can try in `didTransition` hook `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function() { //do your html stuff. });`

Comment: It worked! Thanks lot :)